# Send multiple variables via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im so noob at this, been working with PHP and Js for like 4 months, sorry if im making a noob question, also, im a spanish speaker, sorry for english grammar fails you are going to read =[

Basically, this is my problem:
In this Php File i have some Vars and VarArrays, i need to send them to another one

```
//First PHP File - This one Search on DataBase, at the end, i have 5 vars, 2 of them are arrays
<?php
$var1 = '1';
$var2 = '2';
$var3 = '3';

$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();

//¿How to json_encode the 5 vars above?//
?>
```

In this one i need to catch the previus values

```
//Second PHP File
<?php
$newVar1 = $_POST['var1'];
$newVar2 = $_POST['var2'];
$newVar3 = $_POST['var3'];

$newArr1 = $_POST['arr1'];
$newArr2 = $_POST['arr2'];
?>
```

I think i have to do something like this, but how should i do it?:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/FIRSTFILE.php",
        data: ????,
        dataType: "json",
        success:
                function(respuesta)
                {
                  $('#MainDiv').load('php/SECONDFILE.php', function(data) {
                      $(this).html(data);
                  });
                  $('#MainDivLabelVar1').val(respuesta.¿¿EncodeStuff??);
                }
 });
```

Comment: How does the code in the php file `php/CATBuscar.php` send back the data? Note you need to echo out a JSON item.

Comment: The variables you are sending up do not match what is in the php file.

Comment: 1. You can't "send" values from PHP to PHP (unless you use `curl` or similar directly). I presume you are rendering one PHP page, and progressing to the other either by normal POST request or by AJAX? 2. Can we see the output of `php/CATBuscar.php` with `id` and `CAT` parameters? You can get it from the Network panel of your browser's Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can encode your data like this

```
json_encode(array(
         'var1'   =>    '1',
         'var2'   =>    '2',
         'var3'   =>    '3',
         'arr1'   =>     array(),
         'arr2'   =>     array()
          ));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line you are sending values in POST to your php file:

```
 data: {id: id, CAT: CAT},
```

So, if you need to receive data like (in file "second.php")

```
<?php
  $newVar1 = $_POST['var1'];
  $newVar2 = $_POST['var2'];
?>
```

You should send it by this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/second.php", 
        data: {var1: 'value1', var2: 'value2'}
});
```

Comment: Maybe i shouldnt add the javascript part, is not part of the PHP code, i know that, what i dont know is why  ajax with the dataType "json" atribute Its returning "[object object]" as ERROR

But the real real problem, is send multiple Vars, some of them are arrays. How to json_encode the 5 vars?

Comment: To json_encode your 5 vars you need to make 1 array with 5 variables. So it should looks like json_encode(array('1','2','3',array(),array()))

Answer (score 0):

you could deocde the json string into object or array

```
$js_array = json_encode(array(
         'var1'   =>    '1',
         'var2'   =>    '2',
         'var3'   =>    '3',
         'arr1'   =>     array('a' => 'mobile', 'b' => 'PC'),
         'arr2'   =>     array('price' => 600, 'day' => 7)
          ));

$decode = json_decode($js_array, true); //decode into array

//you could use or seperate something you get back from json decode like this
foreach($decode as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {  
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            echo "$k => $v <br />";
        }
    } else {
        echo "$key: $value <br />";     
    }
}
```

and the output:

```
var1: 1 
var2: 2 
var3: 3 
a: mobile 
b: PC 
price: 600 
day: 7
```